# How to make VBA code to loop via multiple sheets and copy selected (6) cells

Tags: excel, vba

How to make VBA code to loop via multiple sheets and copy selected (6) cells, and pasted into summary excel sheet with heading format cells made via the VBA code, including sheets numbers, the summary sheet is created via the code ..

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can use the record button to record the macro doing exactly that, after which look at code and you can neaten if needed. There should be no problem doing this at all!

Please review below link.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx